# Google push notification not reaching the app

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app that receives a push notification that my server sends and does further processing. The push notification and everything is working fine on a number of phones. However, there is one phone from a local manufacturer - `Micromax A27` - for which my app's broadcast receiver's `onReceive` never gets called. I tried everything but it's a no go. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Below is my manifest code for registering the receiver:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.wheels.driver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Please note that the above code works on all phones that I have tested till now, except on a particular model - `Micromax A27`.

The full Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wheels.driver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

       <receiver
            android:name="gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.wheels.driver" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="gcm.GcmIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.wheels.driver.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.wheels.driver.Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
         </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.wheels.driver.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
         </activity>
          <activity
            android:name="com.wheels.driver.RequestDetails"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
         </activity>

           <activity
            android:name="com.wheels.driver.TripStarted"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
         </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What's the Android version of the phone that doesn't work? What are the Android versions of the phones that work?

Comment: The android version of the phone that it doesnt work on is 2.3.5 and the other phones ive tested it on were 4.0.1, 4.2.2 and 4.3.

Comment: Well, then the problem is most likely in your manifest. I've noticed that newer versions of Android are less strict regarding the correct way to define the GCM permissions and BroadCast receiver declaration in the manifest. In the part you included, you use `com.wheels.driver` for the receiver intent-filter category. This must be the main package of your app, and the GCM permissions must also use that package name. If you can't find the problem yourself, you can include the full manifest and I'll try to find it.

Comment: Have updated my question with the complete manifest. I cant seems to understand what the issue might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the following permissions :

```
<permission android:name="com.wheels.driver.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.wheels.driver.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

For some reason this error prevents GCM from working only on older Android devices (even though the [official GCM code samples](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) state that it's required).

Comment: Got it Thanks, I stumbled on this link also at the same time :)

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Thanks a ton for your help!!!